# Remove escaped unicode string in java with regex

Tags: java, regex, unicode, escaping

I have string like below

```
"them coming \nLove it \ud83d\ude00"
```

I want to remove this character `"\ud83d\ude00"`. so it will be

```
"them coming \nLove it "
```

How can I achieve this in java? I have tried with code like below but it won't works

```
payload.toString().replaceAll("\\\\u\\b{4}.", "")
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you want to remove them? They are a pair of surrogate that forms a valid code point in astral plane. Anyway, it's unclear whether you want to remove surrogates in your text, or you want to remove all Unicode escape sequences in Java string.

Answer (score 0):

I think `\\\\u\\b{4}.` will not work, because regex treat `\ud83d` as a symbol �, not a literal string. So to match this kind unwanted (for any reason) unicode characters it will be better to exclude character you accept(don't want to replace), so for ecample all ASCII character, and match everything else (what you want to replace). Try with:

```
[^\x00-\x7F]+
```

The `\x00-\x7F` includes Unicode [Basic Latin block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_%28Unicode_block%29).

```
String str = "them coming \nLove it \ud83d\ude00";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]+", ""));
```

will result with:

> them coming
>   Love it

However, you willl hava a problem, if you use national character, any other non-ASCII symbols (ś,ą,♉,☹,etc.).